# Boolean prime ideal Theorem and the existence of nonmeasurable sets

Tags: set-theory

In a well-written wikipedia article titled "Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem" (BPIT) the author states: "A not too well known application of the BPIT is the existence of non-measurable sets". It follows that the existence of non-measurable sets is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice (since the BPIT is strictly weaker than AC, as established by J. D. Halpern and Azriel Lévy). Does anybody know a reference to a direct proof of the existence on non-measurable sets from the BPIT?

Comment: You don't need this to conclude that the existence of non-measurable sets is weaker than AC - just have the first failure of AC occur high in the cumulative hierarchy. In general, no "rank-bounded" fact can imply full AC.

Answer (score 3):

The Boolean prime ideal theorem gives you an ultrafilter $U$ on the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, but any ultrafilter, viewed as a subset of Cantor space $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, is not measurable with respect to the coin-flipping measure.

I described one way to see this in my answer to this question, [A remark of Connes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/57108/1946):

> We may regard $U$ as a subset of $2^\mathbb{N}$, which carries a natural probability measure. But a nonprincipal ultrafilter cannot be measurable there, since the full bit-flipping operation, which is measure-preserving, carries $U$ exactly to its complement, so $U$ would have to have measure $\frac12$, but $U$ is invariant by the operation of flipping any finite number of bits, and so must have measure $0$ or $1$ by [Kolmogorov's zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero-one_law). (See also [this article by Blackwell and Diaconis](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Statistics-probability-and-game-theory/chapter/A-non-measurable-tail-set/10.1214/lnms/1215453560) proving the same fact.)